# counting swap and comparison of quicksort

Tags: c, quicksort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ELEMENTS    1000 
#define OFFSET          100  
#define MAX_LINES       10   
int  a[MAX_ELEMENTS] ;      

int  comp, swap      ; 

void quicksort(int [],int ,int);
void init_step(void);
void print_step(int);
void print_header(char *);
int sorted(int);
void swap1(int*,int*);

int main(void){
  int i;
  int n; 

  srandom(time(0));          

  print_header("random");
  for (n = OFFSET; n <= MAX_ELEMENTS; n += OFFSET) {
    init_step();              
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      a[i] = random() % n ;   
    }

    quicksort(a,0,n-1);        
    print_step(n);            
  }

  print_header("ascending order");
  for (n = OFFSET; n <= MAX_ELEMENTS; n += OFFSET) {
    init_step();              
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      a[i] = i ;               
    }

    quicksort(a,0,n-1);        
    print_step(n);             
  }

  print_header("descending order");
  for (n = OFFSET; n <= MAX_ELEMENTS; n += OFFSET) {
    init_step();               
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      a[i] = n - i ;           
    }

    quicksort(a,0,n-1);        
    print_step(n);           
  }

  return 0;
}

void init_step(void){
  swap = 0; comp = 0;
}

void print_header(char *s) {
  printf("%s\n   n, comparison, swap, check", s);
  printf("\n");
}

void print_step(int n){
  printf("%4d, %8d, %8d", n, comp, swap);

  if (sorted(n)) { 
    printf(", sorted\n");
  } else {
    printf(", unsorted\n");
  }
}

int sorted(int n) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i < n-1; i++)
    if (a[i] > a[i+1]) return 0;
  return 1;
}

void swap1(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
    swap++;
}

void quicksort(int number[25],int first,int last){
   int i, j, pivot, temp;

   if(first<last){
      pivot=first;
      i=first;
      j=last;

      while(i<j){
         while(number[i]<=number[pivot]&&i<last)
            i++;
        comp++;
         while(number[j]>number[pivot])
            j--;
        comp++;
         if(i<j){
            swap1(&number[i], &number[j]);
         }
      }

      temp=number[pivot];
      number[pivot]=number[j];
      number[j]=temp;
      quicksort(number,first,j-1);
      quicksort(number,j+1,last);

   }
}
```

so i have this code to count comparison and swap of quicksort at c max element means the maximum data and offset means Incremental value of the number of data.
the one i want to ask is for the random case is count perfectly but for descending and ascending case the value of the comparison and swap is all the same. and swap values is always 0
to be more specific i will post the result below

```
random
|   n   |comparison| swap| check|
|:---:  |:--------:|:---:|:----:|
|100    |   316    |  89 |sorted|
|200    |   756    | 244 |sorted|
|300    |  1156    | 375 |sorted|
|400    |  1630    | 552 |sorted|
|500    |  2164    | 745 |sorted|
|600    |  2682    | 932 |sorted|
|700    |  3202    |1125 |sorted|
|800    |  3776    |1351 |sorted|
|900    |  4286    |1539 |sorted|
|1000   |  4732    |1678 |sorted|

ascending order
|   n |comparison| swap| check |
|:---:|:--------:|:---:|:-----:|
|100  |    198   |  0  | sorted|
|200  |    398   |  0  | sorted|
|300  |    598   |  0  | sorted|
|400  |    798   |  0  | sorted|
|500  |    998   |  0  | sorted|
|600  |   1198   |  0  | sorted|
|700  |   1398   |  0  | sorted|
|800  |   1598   |  0  | sorted|
|900  |   1798   |  0  | sorted|
|1000 |   1998   |  0  | sorted|

descending order
|   n |comparison| swap| check |
|:---:|:--------:|:---:|:-----:|
|100  |    198   |  0  | sorted|
|200  |    398   |  0  | sorted|
|300  |    598   |  0  | sorted|
|400  |    798   |  0  | sorted|
|500  |    998   |  0  | sorted|
|600  |   1198   |  0  | sorted|
|700  |   1398   |  0  | sorted|
|800  |   1598   |  0  | sorted|
|900  |   1798   |  0  | sorted|
|1000 |   1998   |  0  | sorted|
```

is there any one know why my ascending and descending case show same value of comparison and swap count?
and i think for the ascending comparison count is not supposed to be this high isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
temp = number[pivot];
number[pivot] = number[j];
number[j] = temp;
```

That looks like a swap, but you don't count it as one.  You also have:

```
while (number[i] <= number[pivot] && i < last)
    i++;
comp++;
```

The `comp++;` is outside the loop, so you are miscounting the comparisons too.  That occurs twice.

With this version of your code, I get more plausible results:

```
/* SO 7273-8321 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ELEMENTS    1000
#define OFFSET          100
#define MAX_LINES       10

int a[MAX_ELEMENTS];
int comp, swap;

void quicksort(int[], int, int);
void init_step(void);
void print_step(int);
void print_header(char *);
int sorted(int);
void swap1(int *, int *);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int n;

    srandom(time(0));

    print_header("random");
    for (n = OFFSET; n <= MAX_ELEMENTS; n += OFFSET)
    {
        init_step();
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = random() % n;
        }
        quicksort(a, 0, n - 1);
        print_step(n);
    }

    print_header("ascending order");
    for (n = OFFSET; n <= MAX_ELEMENTS; n += OFFSET)
    {
        init_step();
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = i;
        }
        quicksort(a, 0, n - 1);
        print_step(n);
    }

    print_header("descending order");
    for (n = OFFSET; n <= MAX_ELEMENTS; n += OFFSET)
    {
        init_step();
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = n - i;
        }
        quicksort(a, 0, n - 1);
        print_step(n);
    }

    return 0;
}

void init_step(void)
{
    swap = 0;
    comp = 0;
}

void print_header(char *s)
{
    printf("%s\n   n, comparison, swap, check", s);
    printf("\n");
}

void print_step(int n)
{
    printf("%4d, %8d, %8d", n, comp, swap);

    if (sorted(n))
    {
        printf(", sorted\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf(", unsorted\n");
    }
}

int sorted(int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

void swap1(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
    swap++;
}

void quicksort(int number[25], int first, int last)
{
    int i, j, pivot, temp;

    if (first < last)
    {
        pivot = first;
        i = first;
        j = last;

        while (i < j)
        {
            while (number[i] <= number[pivot] && i < last)
            {
                i++;
                comp++;
            }
            while (number[j] > number[pivot])
            {
                j--;
                comp++;
            }
            if (i < j)
            {
                swap1(&number[i], &number[j]);
            }
        }

        temp = number[pivot];
        number[pivot] = number[j];
        number[j] = temp;
        swap++;
        quicksort(number, first, j - 1);
        quicksort(number, j + 1, last);
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
random
   n, comparison, swap, check
 100,      644,      172, sorted
 200,     1703,      367, sorted
 300,     2845,      592, sorted
 400,     3493,      840, sorted
 500,     5020,     1094, sorted
 600,     6206,     1327, sorted
 700,     7279,     1617, sorted
 800,     8784,     1827, sorted
 900,     9342,     2143, sorted
1000,    10185,     2470, sorted
ascending order
   n, comparison, swap, check
 100,     5049,       99, sorted
 200,    20099,      199, sorted
 300,    45149,      299, sorted
 400,    80199,      399, sorted
 500,   125249,      499, sorted
 600,   180299,      599, sorted
 700,   245349,      699, sorted
 800,   320399,      799, sorted
 900,   405449,      899, sorted
1000,   500499,      999, sorted
descending order
   n, comparison, swap, check
 100,     4999,       99, sorted
 200,    19999,      199, sorted
 300,    44999,      299, sorted
 400,    79999,      399, sorted
 500,   124999,      499, sorted
 600,   179999,      599, sorted
 700,   244999,      699, sorted
 800,   319999,      799, sorted
 900,   404999,      899, sorted
1000,   499999,      999, sorted
```

Comment: thanks for the comment jonathan leffler and support ukraine. by any chance  support ukraine which comp do you means? and where should i put the comp++?jonathtan leffler i think count swap is still a little bit different cause at this  if (i < j)
            {
                swap1(&number[i], &number[j]);
            } the swap count isn't counted at all isn't it?